# why am i getting null value from my database in laravel when trying to find specific user?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Am trying to display information of a specific student in my database using student ID. I seem to get null value yet the student exist in the database. i seriously do not know why am getting this null value.

this is what i did

```
public function showResult(Request $request, $std_id)
    {   

      $user = Student::find($std_id);
      if (empty($user)) {
        return redirect('/user')
      }

        $academic = $request->input('academic_year');
        $std = $request -> input('studentID');

       $results = DB::table('students')
                  ->select('*')
                  ->join('results', 'students.std_id', 'results.student_results_id')
                  ->where('student_results_id', '=', $std)
                  ->where('academic_year', '=', $academic)
                  ->get();


                  return view('resultsdisplay',[
                  'results' => $results,
                  ]);
        }
}
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('/student/resultshow/{std_id}', 'ResultsController@showResult');
```

My ***studentprofile.blade.php***

```
<li class="list-group-item">
            <form action="{{URL::to('/student/resultshow/{!! $studentprofilePage->std_id !!}')}}" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">

             <input type="text" name="studentID" value="{!! $studentprofilePage->std_id !!}" hidden="">

            <input type="text" name="academic_year" placeholder="Academic year.."> 
            <button>view</button>    
            </form>
            </li>
```

Comment: What is the result of `dd($std_id)` ? Maybe you are not getting that variable correctly.

Comment: this is the value ```null```

Comment: So the problem is in that variable, how are you trying to pass that variable to that function? Edit your question, please. Post your controller, route, etc. And write how are you trying to execute that function

Comment: Your form is the issue I think.  Blade isn't reading the right escape within the php directive.  See the final part of my answer - double directives don't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to test.  First, check the `$std_id` variable as it comes into the method to make sure this is translating correctly from your form / route into the method.

```
public function showResult(Request $request, $std_id){
     dd($std_id);
```

If this is a properly formed integer/id, check the database just to make sure that id is actually assigned within the students table, and it is not soft-deleted if you are using soft-deletes (`deleted_at` column).

If all good there, take a look at the **Student** model itself.  Is the model pointing to the right table?  Laravel assumes the table is named 'students'.  If not, have you declared the table within the model?

```
public $table = 'mySpecialStudentsTableName';
```

Also, is the id type correct against what is coming in.  IE I assume it is an integer, but if it is looking for a string / uuid, is that properly coming out of that `$std_id` variable?

Finally - your form is not sending the correct id:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/student/resultshow/{!! $studentprofilePage->std_id !!}')}}"
```

Should be:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('/student/resultshow/'. $studentprofilePage->std_id)}}"
```

Comment: It's working now..The problem was with the form route. i change it and it's working.. Thanks alot